# Magento - Use different phtml files for cart and checkout order review screens

Tags: magento, e-commerce, checkout, cart, onestepcheckout

I have a very similar issue as the question from this post:
[Magento - Have different set of fields and labels for cart and checkout (order review) screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267090/magento-have-different-set-of-fields-and-labels-for-cart-and-checkout-order-r)

My question is the same but I am trying to achieve something different so the accepted answer does not help me. In the site I am developing grand total of the cart requires a colspan of 4 and the review screen of the checkout requires a colspan of 3. The only way I can think of doing this is to use a separate phtml file, but I can't figure out how to implement this.

I have tried for a few days to do this and I can't workout where to link the 2 phtml files to display where I require them. From what I can see the grandtotal.phtml file is linked to the block Mage_Tax_Block_Checkout_Grandtotal using a protected field in the block itself. So by changing this it changes the display for both cart and checkout simultaneously.

My first thought was to try to override the block in the local code pool but I am unsure what to put in the rewrite directive and also this would still have the effect of overriding the block for the cart and the checkout. My next thought was to try make the changes in the local.xml layout file but I don't know what I need to hook into to change just the onstep review total or whether it is possible override a field that is set in a block in this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.